# A thing that paginates

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a single word noun for something that splits something info pages? At a guess I came up with:

- paginator
- pager

Paginator *seems* right, but it doesn't look right, while pager looks right, but seems confusing, while I've heard programs such as `more`, `less` and `nano` described as terminal pagers, I can't see anywhere else that the term pager seems to mean this.

Comment: If it helps for context I came up with this question while working on a system where you have multiple ways to produce sets of n items at a time to return within a rest API, I'd hope though that this isn't too important to the question here

Comment: *Paginate* means to apply page numbers.  Is that what you want?  A pager is an obsolete wireless device.  I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: @deadrat but paginate is a verb, and possibly not quite what's going on, as the thing I'm naming splits things into pages, rather than just numbering them. As for pager, words can have multiple meanings, but the most common meaning is what you say. What I don't know is whether this is because it's not a meaning you commonly need, or because there is a better word

Answer (score 1):

Pager is probably as close as you're going to get.

But it doesn't describe the thing you think it describes. In computing terms pagination is applied by the shell. [MORE & LESS are output redirectors.](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html) They accept the standard output of something, buffer it, and allow you to page through it. Thus they are pagers because they engage in the action of paging (turning pages) not paginating (creating pages).

Paginating is only one parameter of formatting, and doesn't live in vacuum. So the reason you can't turn up a "paginator" in the dictionary is because no one has bothered to use it often enough, and it looks like we won't need to; [paginating is a subset of functions that may be carried out by Parsers, Formatters, Processors, Typesetters, and other already existing '*rs'.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination)

Comment: I work at a web firm and, at least around the office, we call the programming that controls the pagination the "pager."

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo uses *[paginator](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/paginator/)*

> A continuous paginator is one that has no number of items to display. This is created by simply instantiating a new paginator.

Edit:

Pager isn't standard. *Paginator* is used in Yahoo's widely deployed YUI library, [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html), [Python Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/), [this Backbone library](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator) and [this one](https://backgridjs.com/ref/extensions/paginator.html), [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html), [Doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html), and [this npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paginator), which is named *Paginator*.
Django alone [includes such sites as](https://www.shoop.io/en/blog/25-of-the-most-popular-python-and-django-websites/) Pinterest, The Onion, Instagram, Disqus, Spotify, The Washington Post and many others.  Bootstrap uses Pager.